# Does boost::bind make a copy of a member function

Tags: boost, bind, pointer-to-member

Boost::bind documentation states:

> By default, bind makes a copy of the provided function object. boost::ref and boost::cref can be used to make it store a reference to the function object, rather than a copy.

I am seeing excessive news and deletes in my code when I use boost::bind with a pointer to a member function. The documentation is unclear to me whether boost::bind(&classname::functionname,...) makes a copy of the function.

Or maybe the question makes no sense and as it is converting a member function into a function object it obviously has to new the function object.

So my question is there a way I can bind to a member function and avoid the new and delete?

Comment: Can you show the code where boost::bind causes new/delete? Perhaps, you bind some object by value, while its copy-constructor performs deep copying of some internal data?

Comment: Igor, the code is very templated and to try to pull out a sensible version of it would take a long time. I have swapped the bind for a direct call through a (nasty) member function pointer and it does not hit new and delete. I think it is dynamically newing and deleting the function object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my experiments (boost 1.49), `boost::bind` does not use dynamic memory for its own implementation. With this code

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

int f(int a , int b) {
  return a>b ? a+b : a-b;
}

int main()
{
  auto a = boost::bind(f, _1, 2);
  return a(0);
}
```

I tried breaking on `operator new` variants in gdb and it didn't fire. So I suspect your problem is actually that `boost::bind` is making copies of either the bound arguments (compare the output of these [two](http://codepad.org/0Ytk5xZ6) [snippets](http://codepad.org/ubgohkH3)) or the call arguments. Search for something among these that could allocate memory while copying, and try to get rid of it.

If you're using a C++11 compiler, you can get away with `boost::bind` completely and use a lambda function instead. The example would be transformed to

```
auto a = [&](int a1) { return f(a1, 2); }
```

That would only copy if you'd capture objects by value.

EDIT: With the code you posted, try changing the line in question to

```
TConstIterator pIt = std::find_if(rtContainer.begin(), rtContainer.end(), 
  boost::bind(&TValueType::bSameSocket, boost::cref(rtData), _1));
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That should make it better; report if it doesn't.

Comment: jpalecek, see below. I changed the bind to a member function pointer call and the new/delete calls went. I wonder if the difference is that I'm binding to a member function?

Comment: @Ant: No, see the snippets I linked. They bind to a member function. I believe you that the allocation didn't happen when you changed you code to pure function call; I just assume these calls were not due to `bind` itself, but due to eg. arguments that could be passed by reference, but were passed by value in case of bind. Show us the real code if you want to know better.

Comment: I think this is enough code to demonstrate what I am doing. [link](http://codepad.org/WoQDrBNv). The code that caused the new/delete problem is commented out and replaced by the code below it.

Comment: @Ant: see edit; I'm just a bit confused that you have the similar code just below, in the `vMoveIf` function. Have you tried that already?

Comment: Many thanks you were exactly right, my code change just worked around the problem and hid it. Changing the code to boost::cref(rtData) makes the code fast too. So it was copying the parameter that was causing the new and deletes. I have learnt a lot!

Answer (score 1):

What gets copied is the *pointer* to that method, so no new/delete involved. What `bind` returns is a function object that gets created and destroyed at some point, but again no dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: By created and destroyed aren't you implying new and delete? If I run the bind 10,000 times and hit break I am always in a new, delete, malloc or free function. The call stack goes straight back to the bind. I have swapped the code for a member function pointer and it now runs thousands of times faster.

Comment: OK, `bind` may use `new` and `delete` in its internal implementation. But you asked if bind did a copy of the function, and it actually doesn't do that copy.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell if you use boost::bind in code such as to create a function object to act as the predicate in a find_if the function object is newed and deleted and this is what was causing my code to run slowly.

My question was: is there a way I can bind to a member function and avoid the new and delete?

I worked around the boost::bind by iterating through the list myself calling a member function through a member function pointer.

The type of the member pointer function is derived from template parameters for the list and its stored data types, but the same technique works whether the types are templated or not.

This solution reduced the user perception of response for a particular action from 5 minutes to effectively immediately.